# Multi Issue with Super and

Tags: java, inheritance

I am having an issue with some of the code I am working on and am looking at the errors on the sidebar of Eclipse and can't seem to figure out how to fix the issue, I search the issues with the lines in question but still cant seem to find it (spending 12 hours+ trying to fix without trying to post.)

I am trying to get the main file (StartUp.java) to display a panel from another class. Its a standard character sheet idea im using.

```
package mainGame;
import javax.swing.*;
public class StartUp extends JFrame{

public DataSheet(){
    super("CharacterSheet");
    setSize(1024, 768);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLookAndFeel();
    CharacterSheet charSheet = new CharacterSheet();
    add(charSheet);
    setVisible(true);
}

private void setLookAndFeel(){
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
                "com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
        SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(this);
    } catch (Exception exc){
        System.err.println("Couldn't use the system look and feel: " + exc);
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    DataSheet frame = new DataSheet();
}

}
```

Thanks in advance

Errors included 
Line 5 - The serializable class StartUp does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field of type long

Line 7 - Return Type for Method missing

Line 8 - Constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor

Line 29 shows 2 errors of the same - Constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor

Purpose was to have the StartUp just display the panel from the CharacterSheet class to the Frame of the StartUp class.

Comment: Pointers? Java?  You sure?

Comment: Wow I will edit the question I messed that up >.< Thanks for catching it Steve

Comment: @Keppil the issues are mainly on the StartUp File, line 5 7 8 and 29, feel free to copy/paste the code to your IDE

Comment: Most I think would appreciate it if you post your code here with your question rather than as a link.  The easier it is for us to learn about your problem, usually the quicker and better the help you may receive. If you click on the question mark in the upper right corner of your edit window, you will see information on how to format your code properly when posting it here.

Comment: The absolute worst thing you can do is to say "It errored. Please help." We **MUST MUST MUST** see a) your error message, and b) your code. Posting on pastebin is fine on other sites, but here we expect you to give us a complete copy of your code, in text form, embedded into the post, complete with full error messages. The cryptic stack trace may mean nothing to you, but it's a critical clue for us!

Comment: Also, keep in mind that errors often appear many lines before the compiler says they appear.

Comment: @MathSquared11235 Im sorry, Im really new to stackexchanged so im still working on the rules of posting and understanding how everything works here

Comment: @Yudra: thanks for the code, and 1+ up-vote to your question.

Comment: @Yudra That's fine, just keep what I said in mind. Consider reading the FAQ or "help" on the top bar.

Comment: OK I added more information about the issue and the purpose of the code to give a better idea of my intentions with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your problem is that the class name is StartUp, but the constructor is DataSheet(). Its recomended, in most of cases that you define only one class per file. So StartUp clas must implement a contructor named StartUp(), and be contained in a file named StartUp.java

Best regards.

Comment: I would like to say thanks for that information It works for what I intended it to do. Thank-you. Does this need to be done with All classes?

Comment: Short answer, yes. Each class should be in separated files. Name of the file and the class should be the same. There are exceptions like inner classes or anonymous classes, but maybe you should pratice first with "normal" clases.

Comment: Thankyou, I will take your suggestion.